# aborting multiple xhr requests

Tags: javascript, security, xmlhttprequest

Consider the  case: I  have a list of  items and pagination to load them by chunks. On each next page click new XHR call is made to  get a new portion  of  items. When the user clicks really fast I have many xhrs in which actually there is no need as the  user wants only the last clicked page items and also they take resources. So I can abort all but the last one pending requests calling  xhr.abort() for each of them. The question is: **is it secure to abort  multiple xhrs?** I've read that the server might consider it to  be some kind of attack. if so what settings to check with backend guys?

Note: Function that makes xhrs is already debounced by 400 ms.

Comment: I'd personally take the approach of ignoring clicks when there is currently an active request, similar to the though process of disabling a submit button when it's clicked.

Comment: Or cancel the request if you detect a new one or debounce the calls so multiple can not be made quickly.

Comment: the function that happens on click is debounced but still our testers manage to click  simultaneously once per 200 ms and once the  debounce inerval is  changed to 400ms - once per 410 ms, etc. There are still many  requests

Comment: So do not make a call until the last one is returned?

Comment: I do not know which one is the last I  can only abort previous pending

Comment: I mean that the user can continue clicking after he stops for a while (I mean some troublesome guy)

Comment: Maybe save the requests in an array, or to an object with a timestamp so it's easy to select specific requests. Me personally, I just abort all pending xhr requests on any router call that does xhr and I haven't had issues with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than cancel a pending xhr request, you are better off debuffing your event for a few hundred milliseconds before sending the request. Every time you hit the button you will reset a timer that delays the xhr request

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#button')
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'

const request = (function() {
  // save the current ajax request in the closure
  let ajax = null
  return function(url, params, cb) {
    if (ajax) {
      // if there is a current request cancel it
      ajax.abort()
      console.log('aborted ajax request')
    }
    // set a new xhr
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
        // run the callback with the response
        cb(JSON.parse(ajax.responseText))
        // remove the previous request
        ajax = null
      }
    }
    ajax.open('GET', url, true)
    ajax.send(params)
  }
})()

const clickCallback = debuff(function(e) {
  console.log('clicked')
  // make the xhr request
  request(url, null, function(response) {
    console.log('response', response)
  })
}, 100)
                             
button.addEventListener('click', clickCallback, false)

function debuff(fn, delay) {
  let timer = null
  return function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(e => fn(e), delay || 250, e)
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button">debuffed click</button>
```

Comment: thanks, but its already implemented as I wrote in comments and I  still have the cases when I need to  abort the requests

Comment: @OlenaHoral ok sorry I did not see that.

Comment: @OlenaHoral I have updated my answer. This saves the current ajax request to the `request` closure and cancels any previous requests if there is any pending.